# Two onion links to one site

Tags: configuration

I want to make two onion links to one site on my web server

I created a new address with mkp224o. Got the hostname file and 2 keys.
I put it in var/lib/tor

Edited the torrc
Now it's like this:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/.
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80

HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/torservice/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

But it doesn't work.
And after editing torrc the link which is in /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/ stops working.

If you return it as it was, then 1 site works:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80

#HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/torservice/
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

If you do this, nothing works again. It says that the onion link is not found:

```
#HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
#HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80

HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/torservice/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
```

By the way, the nginx configuration looks like this

```
server {
listen 127.0.0.1:80;
root /var/www;
client_max_body_size 100M;
charset utf-8;
index index.html;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to run 2 links on one site?

Comment: Permissions in the var/lib/tor folder

`drwx--S--- 3 debian-tor debian-tor 4096 Nov 28 17:31 hidden_service
drwx--S--- 2 debian-tor debian-tor 4096 Nov 29 13:23 torservice
`

Answer (score 0):

It's OK to run whatever quantity of links you like. Let's walk through a check list:

- **Folder permissions** - check all the folders specified for a proper permissions and files inside them. If there are empty folders after start - put Tor in a debug mode via command line and re-launch it and read carefully, the error or a problem will be described there
- **Tor's part of the job** - it's *just* a tunnel, like STunnel, and **nothing** more. So it bumps your TCP connection to the ports you're specifying. You can use 127.0.0.x/8 subnet with a *distinct* IP addresses for every named site - for HTTPS and HTTP/2.0 setup simplicity
- **NGinX's part of the job** - I do recommend using HTTPS+HTTP/2.0 for a speed boost-up, especially noticeable on Tor or other darknet encapsulation: it will save the resources by utilizing a single TCP connection and also it can be used for a fine grained security like a client certificate verification e.t.c... For port 80 just set up one global redirector that will bounce the quey up exactly as it is, but to the https proto, it will save your day